# How to boot M2 Pci express Card HP Gen8 Dl360P

Tags: pci-express

I recently purchased the HP GEN8 DL360P server. I wanted to install an operating system to use M2 with a pci express card on this server. However, the server does not start boot with the pci card. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to adjust the BIOS/UEFI settings for the system to make sure the system sees the drive on the PCIe card, and that it is at the top of the boot order or just after removable media such as an attached USB memory stick and any internal DVD-ROM drives.